# How did my launcher turn green?

Tags: unity, 15.04, themes

I have a brand new System76 machine, which shipped with 15.04 and Unity. I'm getting it set up and somewhere along the line I managed to turn my launcher green. I am still using the "ambiance" theme, but suddenly the launcher is this cloying shade of turquoise and I absolutely loathe it.

The problem is that I can't figure out when this happened. At some point I installed CCSM and then realized I didn't want it, and removed it, but I'm not sure either was what did it. Either way ... how do I change it back to boring old ambiance slate?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Also, what colour is your background? I've notice in my 15.04 installation that the launcher likes to change colour to match my background. I currently use a photograph of a field of heather, so my launcher is a nice, mellow purple colour. This could be the culprit.

Comment: @HeatherBrown it was the background, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This by default happens automatically when you change your wallpaper.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Launch it and click on "Launcher". "Appearance" should be on "Based on wallpaper" but you can also select a custom color.